# Local Connection String

Tags: c#

Any one help me out in making a string. i want to connect with local database, my local db has no password. I m using below string to connect with database but getting error unable to open connection for user

```
string _connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=CRM;Integrated Security=False;User Id=Ali-Pc;Password= ? ;connection Timeout=0";
```

Comment: Well you're currently specifying your password as "?" - have you tried just removing the Password part from the connection string?

Comment: If you're using Windows Security you must have `"Integrated Security=True;"`

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention what you're trying to connect to, but this site is very useful for finding 
the connection strings to most databases

[Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

You probably want integrated security set to true and no password